# How can I remove the last 20 % of a dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a dataset and want to remove the last 20 % of the rows

I have a dataset and want to remove the last 20 % of the rows

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: At least add some lines from the dataset. and also what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. And [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the dataset if you are using `pandas` and `python`

You can do something like that.

```
df = df.iloc[: -int(df.shape[0] * 0.2), :] # 0.2 is 20 % of the rows
```

`iloc` is used to select rows by number (integer location)